# Recursively download files from Blackboard

Tags: download-manager

I would like to recursively download all files from the subfolders of the root folder that I designate in a website running [Blackboard](http://blackboard.com/).

I know that Chrome and Firefox have add-ons (DownLoadthemall and Getthemall, respectively) to do something like this, but they don't download recursively. Are there any add-ons that do this recursively?

I would write a script to do it in Python, but Blackboard requires a password / might give me issues trying to crawl it.

A browser add-on is preferred,  but a stand-alone tool would be fine, too.

Comment: Could be a duplicate depending on how the site is [password protected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828031/wget-entire-http-directory-that-is-password-protected).

Comment: (1) With "blackboard", are you referring to http://blackboard.com? (2) Must the solution be a browser add-on (for Chrome and/or Firefox, or any browser at all?), or can it be a stand-alone tool?

Comment: Yes, blackboard.com--the site all the schools use. I would prefer a browser add-on, but a stand-alone tool would be fine.

Comment: do you happen to know whether Blackboard has any API?